Docker compose - one replica not available
I'm using docker compose with the following file:
services:
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    ports:
      - "9444-9450:9443"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2   

And indeed have two containers running with different ports (9444 and 9445). However, only one is accessible from the outside (on port 9445). How come? What should I change to have each replica available from the outside?
Thanks - Christian
